# haproxy single socket per client cert

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, haproxy, client-certificates

Is is possible to configure HAProxy to only allow single connection per client certificate (based on CN or other attribute)?

Each client should be able to connect even if it has already open connections, though, after successful authentication any previous connection for that certificate should be dropped immediately.

I do not think ACL's would work for this purpose.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? What purpose would be served by such a restriction?

Comment: security policy. we use single persistent tcp connection per client. if we do not use tcp keepalives the previous connection from a client would be automatically cleaned up on reconnect. we will use keepalives if this is not supported